# Visual Studio: automatically build multiple solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a number of webapi solutions that are called at various places from a single web app. When testing locally this requires me to get latest, open each solution in VS and build it before i can even get to running the "real" app which may or may not hit any of those webapi projects I already mentioned.  Its a good 15 min PIA to test.

Is there some tool that would allow me to automatically build a list of projects **locally**.. I'm not talking about TFS Auotmated Builds?

---

OK I'm trying Power Shell but this is only opens explorer.  What command should I be using?

```
$proj_paths = "D:\TF\Dev\Claim",
"D:\TF\Diary\DEV"
$msbuild = "D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

foreach ($p in $proj_paths){
    Write-Host """$msbuild""" """$p"""    
    Start-Process $msbuild """$p"""
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into scripting the builds using Powershell?

Comment: yes.. will update the question

Comment: I use a continuous integration (Powershell) script to perform multiple builds in one invocation.  It runs devenv.com and not MSBuild.

Comment: @rrirower Is this an app that uses powershell or simply a powershell script. If its a script would you mind sharing?

Comment: Just a Powershell script.  In fact, it's a series of scripts.  Unfortunately, I can't share.  Let me know if you have specific questions.